# Xcode static library appears twice

Tags: xcode4

I added the OCMock static library in Xcode with some header files.

I'm not sure what's changed since I added it but the file now appears twice in the Project Navigator - once at the top level and once under the usr/lib folders.

[image: duplicate]

How do I get rid of the second (highlighted) listing?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you added OCMock's whole "`usr`" folder via a folder reference, most likely by accident.

You have three choices for a solution:

1)

Remove the "`usr`" folder from your list of files & folders in your project, and re-add just the "`include`" folder via folder reference (I'm presuming you want to use the folder reference so you can pick up the latest header files that are in there?).

2)

Add the required header files to your project directly (i.e. not using the folder reference).

3)

Or get rid of the first "`libOCMock.a`" library and just rely on the folder reference to pick up the static library living under the "`usr`" hierarchy.

Comment: Can you clarify solution 1)? The OCMock instructions say the usr folder has to be included (see http://ocmock.org/ then click on the iOS tab and go to the "Adding the library to a project" section).

Comment: Why not just move the "`libOCMock.a`" (and the "`lib`" folder in general) ***out*** and away from the within the "`usr`" folder), and into another folder somewhere in your source code hierarchy?